# How can I perform a search as if I were in the past?

Tags: google-search

Simple question: I wonder whether it is possible to perform a Google search omiting all results from 2012 on, for example.

Comment: This question was in danger of being closed as off-topic, for [being a Web application recommendation requests](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I have edited it so that it is about the Google search engine only, since it is an interesting question and already has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

On Google.com, after you have done a search, you can click the Tools button (rightmost button under the search bar AFTER you have searched). If you do this, some options become available, one of which is time. The presets are all for finding recent results, but with the Custom Range option, you can also specify anything before a certain date (just leave the From field open)